# HTML/CSS make div snap to the windows's bottom

Tags: css

I've this div:

```
<style>
#asd{
    height:auto;
width:1024px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#093;
}

</style>
```

I want this div's bottom to always reach down to the window's bottom, whatever the window's current size is.

what I tried so far adding to #asd's css, without the expected results:
margin-bottom:0px;
or
height:100%;
or
bottom:0px;

any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

to your class...

```
#asd{
  height:auto;
  width:1024px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:#093;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: my probleme is: the div wont stay on the middle anymore

Comment: I don't understand... do you want it in the middle or on the bottom?

Comment: the div's bottom should touch the window's bottom at all times. It's X coordinate should stay on the middle. hope it makes sense

Comment: Are you saying that it's not currently centered horizontally?

Comment: Add left:0;right:0; to your class, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/SbcQd/

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting `position: fixed` If you use fixed you'll then need to tell it where to fix to:

```
#asd{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#093;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

So to tell it to be at the bottom of the page you use `bottom: 0px`

Comment: Apparently, with CSS as with Perl, TMTOWTDI (There's More Than One Way To Do It)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-height` to 100%:

```
<style>
#asd{
    min-height:100%;
    width:1024px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#093;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I changed out height for min-height.

Comment: but now the element will be the height of the entire page... Meaning you can only click on this div and nothing in the page... Unless I am mistaken..

Comment: try it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_min-height Just set min-height to 100% instead of 100px. It will take up 100% of its parent container. Make all containers that contain it take 100% and you're done, as Mike Legacy noted.

Comment: think you missed my point. I've no doubt that it will work, but it will have undesired side effects... or i'm wrong

Comment: the div stays the same, nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set a height and width of the 100% on the body, html element like so:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then use min and max-height on the ASD element:

```
#asd{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%:
    max-height: 100%;
    width:1024px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#093;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the containing elements Body and Html!

Comment: Your question is vague, that is why you are getting multiple answers for different scenarios. By "wanting it to reach the bottom" do you want the box to be 100% height at all time, or do you want if fixed to the bottom?

Comment: Jesse, I used to run into all kinds of issues without those tags. Most frameworks (normalize, etc) already include them, but I'm assuming he isn't using any of those.